# Performing a mouse click without moving cursor

Tags: c#, .net, mouseevent, mouse

I couldn't find any solution except moving the cursor by `Cursor` class, clicking with `mouse_event` then moving the cursor to its old position. I am playing with `SendInput` function right now but still no chance for a good solution. Any advice?

Comment: What flavor of .Net C#, VB?, ASP.Net

Comment: What type of object are you trying to click on?

Comment: I am trying to click some position on browser. First, i get the coordinates of the point that i want to click then i run the click function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use Win32 API. 
Use pInvoked SendMessage from user32.dll

[pInvoked Function](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendMessage)

Then read about mouse events:
[Mouse Input on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And then read about: [System events and Mouse Mess.......](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Also there is lots of info:
[Info](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants.WM)

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example following the approach Hooch suggested.

I created a form which contains 2 buttons. When you click upon the first button, the position of the second button is resolved (screen coördinates). Then a handle for this button is retrieved. Finally the SendMessage(...) (PInvoke) function is used to send a click event without moving the mouse.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, 
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "WindowFromPoint", 
        CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point point);

    private const int BM_CLICK = 0x00F5;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify the point you want to click
        var screenPoint = this.PointToScreen(new Point(button2.Left, 
            button2.Top));
        // Get a handle
        var handle = WindowFromPoint(screenPoint);
        // Send the click message
        if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            SendMessage( handle, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hi", "There");
    }
}
```