# Java Robot ghost mouse clicks

Tags: java, awt, mouse, awtrobot

Is it possible to make a mouse click on certain coordinates (e.g. x 300, y 400) without moving the "actual" mouse pointer?

I am currently doing a workaround with mouseMove(), mousePress()&mouseRelease + returning to the previous position. That is not an actual good solution. Another possibilty would be making a program in C that does that and call it all the time but I think it's even worse.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You will need to use native code to achieve this.  Here's a C# example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315196/performing-mouse-click-without-moving-cursor

Comment: what do you want to click in that coordinate?

Comment: Thanks for the example, that was what I was talking about, "native code" (didn't know the word).

Comment: I want to click an arrow in a music application, would be even better if I achieved it when the window is minimized. Already found a thread about it, but it's a way harder in my case, because the name of the window changes all the time.